# Is it possible to give user free subscription?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Is it possible to give in gift free subscription for some users using google services? It could look like some promo-codes that user can enter and get his free subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to design this system, you can access the users account info by AccountManager.getAccounts to get a list of all account names on the device(but it requires GET_ACCOUNTS permission), and with that, you can update a field on the backend to *True* something like using_google_services=TRUE.

This check of users google account can also be done at the time of entering a promo code and apply your google services promo code by yourself at the backend.

And now on depending on the promo code, you can give free subscription.

OR

You can create a subscription from google console, configure it and then add google play bill to your app. Under the Promotions tab choose Add new promotion of your google_service_promo_code and you can then check the services in app and use it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Having own back-end solving issue, that's right. But what about the abilities of google services itself? Like example, I was thinking about using some billing API to create subscription for user without charging or maybe there are some hidden option for my eyes on developer console I have missed for that?

Comment: You can create a subscription, configure it and then add google play bill to your app.
Under the Promotions tab choose Add new promotion of your google_service_promo_code and you can then check the services in app and use it.

Comment: Yes, I saw that option. But it's only available for the in-app products, not subscriptions.